# Reveal images as user scrolls

Tags: javascript, css, ruby, web

I don't know how to explain this so here is a link of what I want to do: http://www.readiresponse.com/#intro

I know html, css, ruby, Python, and JavaScript. I am most comfortable with ruby and Python but I don't know if you can do that with those languages.

Also if I have to do it in JavaScript what folder should I put it in(html in views, Css in public/css etc...), what do I call the file(html is index.erb, Ruby is application_controller.rb etc....)and how do I link it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site you referred is using parallax effect ~ background and foreground element (or image) scroll parallelly with different speeds. There are many plugins available to use, or you can simply make JavaScript to do so. Hope you will find your answer soon.